# How can I change my own user ID?

Tags: user-management

There is only one user on my system. How can I change its user ID from the default of 1000?

If there are additional steps that would be required in order to avoid breaking the login process on a typical desktop installation, those should be included as part of the answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the reasons for changing a user ID?

Comment: If you commonly exchange data with other systems via NFS, or just some copy method which preserves the UID, it will help if you use the same UID for the same username across systems.

Comment: João got it right. In particular, I'm hoping to match up UIDs with users in Mac OS X so that a shared filesystem carries the intended permissions across operating systems.

Comment: The current version of Nethack (3.6.0) saves games including the current uid in the filename. If you want to sync a save game between machines, you need to match uids. (using a symlink isn't practical)

Comment: For all serious intents and purposes, it is unsupported and all answers here are hacky and risky-to-use.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem is that, like you mentioned, you cannot change your user's UID when it is logged in a session. You have to use another user account to proceed.

But you don't have to create a new user account, promote it to admin, log out, log in to the new admin account, change your primary account's UID, log out, log in to your primary account then delete the new admin user just change your UID. ;)

You can boot into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) (it's an option that appears when you start up your computer, or hold shift right after the BIOS messages complete; Use <kbd>ESC</kbd> on Dell machines running OEM-Ubuntu). This will log you in a root session. Being logged in root **and not your usual user account**, you will be able to modify your UID.

Because the recovery mode only works in  command line interface, once logged into a root session, you will have to:

1. Use [BubbaJ's instructions to remount the root file system in read-write mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/79933): `mount -o remount,rw /`.
2. Use [Luis Alvarado's command](https://askubuntu.com/a/16703): `usermod -u NEW_UID your_username`.
3. Follow [ddeimeke's instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/16719) to update file permissions.
4. Then, reboot your computer (`reboot`), so you can boot in normal mode.

Comment: Doesn't work for Ubuntu 14.04. After doing `usermod -u NEW_UID your_username` and `find / -uid 1000 -exec chown -h 5000 '{}' \+`, reboot leads to a guess-session-only GUI login.

Comment: Maybe, hidden files in the home are not changed properly? Do you use encryption for your home?

Comment: You may wish to check your `/etc/login.defs` and `/etc/adduser.conf` files if you have changed your uid outside of the policies provided in those configuration files. Users outside the policy limits are not displayed in the login loop, but you may change the policy.  See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/811774/283571)

Comment: `usermod: user user_name is currently used by process 1118 ` @Alexandre P.

Comment: Answer is missing advice from @KMarkey's comment. If you change the user ID outside of the configured range in `/etc/login.defs` and `/etc/adduser.conf`, then there is no Gnome login.   This last step fixed it for me.

Answer (score 66):

You can change it in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` and `/etc/shadow` or you use one of the preferred possibilties above. But - most important - you have to change the ownership of all files belonging to the user.

For instance, if the old user id is 1000 and the new one is 5000:

```
find / -uid 1000 -exec chown -h 5000 {} +
```

And the same for the group id (if you change it as well).

```
find / -gid 1000 -exec chgrp -h 5000 {} +
```

Comment: This is a really important point.  Many things will break if you follow the techniques given in the other answers without also doing this.

Comment: I just learnt one should better use `sudo find / -xdev -uid 1000 -exec chown 5000 '{}' \+`, otherwise one would include mounted data (in `/mnt`, which is possibly undesired) and files you better not mess with in `/proc` and `/dev`. See [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28767/6958)

Comment: This is not a good idea. Given the case that /home is on a different filesystem, you will not even change the ownership of your own files.

Comment: On this answer you should change the group and uid permissions, before editing the files in /etc, right?

Comment: It does not matter, what you do first.

Comment: You also want to change ACL permissions on `/media/<USERNAME>` as in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16700/how-can-i-change-my-own-user-id#comment749398_167400).

Comment: I tried the above commands and now I’m not able to the system anymore. I wish the OP posted a step by step solution than providing fix to others solutions.

Comment: why /etc/shadow is required? It just stores the password, right?

Answer (score 40):

Complete solution based on @AlexandreP. and @ddeimeke + official documentation. No reboot necessary.

The Debian/Ubuntu policy is that if there is a user `jim` with user ID `1001`, there is also a group `jim` with group ID `1001`. This solution also updates those group IDs.

1. [Enable the root account](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Enabling_the_root_account):

   ```
   sudo passwd root
   ```
2. If the user is logged in, then log out (also on virtual terminals)
3. Go to VT1: <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-F1</kbd>
4. Log in as root and run this with the user name and old/new UID supplied:

   ```
   # put the information we need in variables
   username=...
   old_uid=`id -u $username`  # looks up current (old) uid
   new_uid=...

   # update the user ID and group ID for $username
   usermod -u $new_uid $username
   groupmod -g $new_uid $username

   # update the file ownerships
   # NB: you cannot combine the next two chowns, or files where 
   # only the uid xor the gid matches won't be updated  
   chown -Rhc --from=$old_uid $new_uid /    # change the user IDs
   chown -Rhc --from=:$old_uid :$new_uid /  # change the group IDs
   ```
5. Log out
6. Log in as `$username`
7. [Disable the root account](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Re-disabling_your_root_account):

   ```
   sudo passwd -dl root
   ```

Comment: Enabling the root account shouldn't be necessary; just use [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

Comment: This should be faster than rebooting, which is why I posted it.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 you also need to fix the extended ACL permissions in /media otherwise automounting (in Nautilus/Nemo) breaks as the old UID remains. 

`sudo setfacl -m "u:<NEWUID>:r-x" /media/<USERNAME>
        sudo setfacl -x "u:<OLDUID>" /media/<USERNAME>`

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. Only had to change the uid, though.

Comment: enabling the root account sounds easier (and less scary) to me than using Recovery Mode.

Comment: @richud.com this is still true as per 20.04. As far as I could find, the only other files with such ACL permissions are in `/var/log/journal`, I think it's save to ignore those, but I have no idea what they're for.

Comment: At least since Ubuntu 18.04, `usermod` updates automatically the uid of files *inside the user's home directory*, see [man usermod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man8/usermod.8.html). So `chown` is only needed for files outside home. It's still needed to update the group id though.

Answer (score 13):

If you go to console and type: `usermod --help` you will get one of the parameters saying:

**-u, --uid UID      new UID for the user account**

so if you want to change the UID for user cyrex then do:

`usermod -u 1000 cyrex`

that would change the uid for cyrex from whatever value it had before to 1000

If you want to do it visually then do this:

Go to

> SYSTEM --> ADMINISTRATION --> USERS
>   AND GROUPS

Select yourself from the list and click on ADVANCED SETTINGS

UID is at the end of that window.

Comment: I tried the graphical method you suggested, but there is a message saying "You can't change user ID while the user is logged in." Have you tested this method?

Comment: Hehe well that is true. I tried with another account. You need to login via root or any other admin account. Then do the graphical way. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

- Goto **System>>Administration>>Users and Groups**

[image]

- Click **Advanced Settings** and goto **Advanced** Tab there in the bottom you will see your user id.
- Change it and click ok.
  [image]

Comment: Should I just ignore the warning in your screenshot, "You can't change user ID while the user is logged in."?

Comment: You have to change it from another another user account to get rid of this warning.

Comment: My question is "How can I **change my own** user ID?". If you intend your answer to be that I should create a new user just to edit this value, you should edit your answer to indicate so.

Answer (score 2):

This is summed up, what at least since Ubuntu 20.04 is needed (for keeping to be able using Automounting, the change in Extended ACL permissions is needed):

I wanted to change a user id and group id for example from default (uid=) 1000 (and gid=1000) to (uid=) 5000 (and gid=5000), so access to mobile drives formatted with ext4 or similar capable systems with uid & gid) are no problem, if the files and archives have the same user id or group id 5000, no matter if another computer or operating system writes data to this (this enables sharing files easily between computers if all the own users have the same uid and gid).

First I created an additional user, logged as new user, changed in terminal with `sudo su -` to the root and then I used the commands

```
find / -uid 1000 -exec chown -h 5000 {} +
```

for changing user id
and

```
find / -gid 1000 -exec chgrp -h 5000 {} +
```

for changing group ID.
(Take care: This changes the rights on all mounted devices. If not wanted, unmount all not desired or narrow the commands in the part `find /` to `find /home/<user>` or else.)

In Fedora this worked but not in Ubuntu totally. For example Automounting did not work. Then I read one has to fix also the extended ACL permissions, otherwise things like Automounting breaks (perhaps problem because of ACL permissions do not appear if no user had this UID & GID already but in my case this was the problem). The change of the Extended ACL permissions seems to be required since Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10.

These are the commands which gave the possibility of Automounting back again:

```
sudo setfacl -m "u:<NEWUID>:r-x" /media/<USERNAME>
```

, which sets UID permissions to the own folder in 'media' and

```
sudo setfacl -x "u:<OLDUID>" /media/<USERNAME>
```

, which deletes permissions to the own user folder for the old UID (yes, this command is not needed for getting Automounting work again, but it ensures another user with the old UID has not access to the media, too).

BTW: A user says, usermod already changes all permissions in home folder since Ubuntu 18.04, but for Automounting at least until Ubuntu 20.04.4 this seems not to be enough yet.

source of information from where I got it and practically tested it since about a month:
[Answers contain all I explain but a bit chaotically and only one advices to fix the Extended ACL permissions for keeping to be able of Automounting.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16700/how-can-i-change-my-own-user-id)

PS: If someone asks why I did not post this as a question with the solution, the I have to say, I do not have enough "karma" in this sites for doing this. So please vote this answer up.

Answer (score 1):

With KDE:
In the Change Advanced User Settings Menu:

Changing from another user does not work for 1000 which is the default user.

you have to do that manually - my experience

Answer (score 1):

First you need to login as root, at least for a while, so let us make this possible:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Reboot, ctrl + alt + f1 to switch to the console, login as root, do the following (ownership in home dir will be taken care of automatically):

```
groupmod --gid NEWGID username
usermod  --uid NEWUID username
```

For your files in places other than your home dir, to this:

```
sudo chown -R username:username /path/to/files
```

Delete and lock the passwd of root, if you want. (I tend to keep it):

```
passwd -dl root
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed [ddeimeke's](https://askubuntu.com/a/16719/75735) instructions with the following changes:

1. I did not logout and instead did `sudo su`
2. I did not touch `/etc/shadow`

I have seen it mentioned in the other answers that you should either boot to recovery or login as `root`. Mine was a fresh Ubuntu 14 install so I was willing to test whether it would work without logging in as `root`. Also I was doing this on an EC2 instance over SSH.