# Cannot lock '/etc/group' in recovery mode

Tags: sudo, recovery-mode

I've currently booted into recovery mode, because I removed my sole user from admin :/

When I run `adduser oadams admin`, I get `gpasswd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.`

For what it's worth, `ls /etc/ | grep "lock"`, returns only `mtab.fuselock`, so there's nothing to delete.

How can I get my user back in the admin group?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check that you are root

```
whoami
```

Check that the root partition is mounted read-write

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

If you see that your partition is mounted as **ro** (*read-only*), try remounting it as **rw**

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Comment: I'm root. As for the output of `cat /proc/mounts`, I get `rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0` so I take that that is read-write. There are a bunch of other lines, all with rw in them, except `/dev/disk/by-uuid/<some long uuid> / ext4 ro,relatime,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0`, which I take is read-only.

Comment: @oadams: see my edit. Please also post `/etc/fstab`, your drive designation (the uuid one) is atypical. The rootfs system is not important here.

Comment: The remount worked, thanks! There isn't enough room here to post the fstab file, but here is (I think) the relevant line: `UUID=0c5c5838-0cba-405e-a3ba-ca2555b90469 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,user_xattr 0       1`

Comment: Then it's OK. Also check the partition for errors or look at logs/SMART data if your HDD is not failing.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it. Should I set the partition back to read-only or would that actually limit system changes on reboot? I'll try leaving it for now, just curious.