# Shutdown during 'apt-get upgrade' and cannot enter system

Tags: apt, dpkg, recovery-mode

I power off my laptop with Ubuntu 11.10 during `apt-get upgrade`, then I power on and choose Ubuntu in grub, but after the Ubuntu logo, a blurred screen comes.

Then I choose `recovery mode` in grub, and then I can type commands as `root`,

I tried `apt-get upgrade` and it tells something wrong with `/var/lib/dpkg/lock`, and suggest `dpkg --configure -a`, then I tried `dpkg --configure -a` but comes something wrong because `read-only file system`, then I have no idea..

Any suggest will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably did not remount your file system as writable, there is a similar question that can help you mount it in recovery mode, please have a look

- [Cannot lock '/etc/group' in recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84277/cannot-lock-etc-group-in-root)

Answer (score 0):

when you choose "ubuntu" in grub, is there only one? Maybe you can try an older ubuntu-version.