# "Authentication Manipulation Error" when trying to reset my password

Tags: password, password-recovery

To reset forgotten password in 12.04 LTS.

I am able to boot the computer. i choose root option and then come to password changing. they ask me to enter new UNIX password which i do type. but at last they give a command saying

> AUTHENTICATION MANIPULATION ERROR

and my password is unchanged.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at our guide on how to reset your password using recovery mode on 12.04 it should help, you probably just need to remount the drive with write permissions after dropping to a root shell using this command :

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Please see [this page on my website](http://fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/resetpassword.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this error occurs in rescue mode, you should be able to reset the password from a live CD/DVD/USB using [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass/147023#147023) or [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/84697/22949).

Answer (score 0):

Before choosing the option root, choose **grub** (to mount the filesystem as read-write). Once it is done, choose **root** option and change the password. Your password will be updated successfully.