# Kubuntu Root Password

Tags: kubuntu, root, password-recovery

I've been running Kubuntu for about a month now, still learning.  All of a sudden as of about two days ago, if I try to install or update software using Muon, it asks for the root password.  I'm assuming this is my administrative password, but that password won't work.  I know I'm typing it in correctly (case sensitive) and I haven't forgotten my admin password because I can log in to my laptop when I first turn it on using the same password.

If the administrative password is not the root password, then what is the root password?  I followed some directions online regarding booting in safe mode, but i can't get the passwd command to work.  I tried that twice and I keep getting an error message telling the password was not changed.  Then I don't know how to exit out of safe mode.  I kept hitting the escape key and that didn't work.  I ended up just powering off my laptop to get out of safe mode.

Comment: have you tried `sudo su -` then `passwd` to change your root password?

Comment: you can change the password.Read this link http://saptarshithelinuxlover.blogspot.in/2014/06/changing-root-password-in-various.html

Comment: [This might be the error](http://askubuntu.com/q/156359/22949) you're getting. If the easier ways don't work, you can [reset it like this](http://askubuntu.com/a/147023/22949). And [here's some info on administrator/root concepts](http://askubuntu.com/q/245201/22949).

Answer (score 0):

To manually set a password for the root user, type in the following in the Terminal:

```
sudo passwd
```

After that you are asked to type in the new root password twice.