# logon screen wont accept details, but terminal does?

Tags: login, login-screen

My Ubuntu machine has suddenly started asking for a username and password when it starts up but does not accept the details I enter. When i go into terminal however, it seems to work fine. I have tried using the

```
passwd <user>
```

change thing but get authentication error. I know i am definately entering the correct details as I always use the same ones.

How can I change the password?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change password for your username.

Enter command like below,

`passwd YOUR_USERNAME`

and make sure that you are logging in using the username you entered earlier.

Comment: This is not different from `passwd`. Running `passwd` as `$USER` is equivalent to running `passwd $USER` as `$USER`. (Running `sudo passwd` is different.) *Also, `passwd YOUR_USERNAME` **is** what the OP ran, but the question's formatting was broken so it didn't appear.*

Answer (score 0):

Try running `passwd` as root. When you run `passwd` as root, unlike when you run it as yourself, you do have to specify the user whose password you want to change:

```
sudo passwd $USER
```

Either keep `$USER` as it is (it will expand to your username), or replace it with your username.

- If you still get an authentication error, [reset the password in recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password).
- If even that doesn't work, you can reset it from a live CD/DVD/USB using [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass/147023#147023) or [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/84697/22949).