# Invalid login password

Tags: login-screen

When I try to login in Ubuntu 16.04 with a valid password an error message is shown an screen saying `invalid password, try again`.
I try to submit the password with no success, then I click on guest account after that I logged out and when I try to login again the same message is shown but the login was successful.

Can someone explain me how this why occurs and how to solve it?

Comment: Is this a brand new installation, and you've never been able to log in, or is this an existing installation where you have been able to log in before? Please see [Why do I keep getting “invalid password” when trying to log in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164093/why-do-i-keep-getting-invalid-password-when-trying-to-log-in?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), as your question might possibly be a duplicate of this one, and there are a lot of suggestions that might help you.

Comment: Thank you @Emily for your reply. This is an old installation and I saw the suggestions then I reset the password from grub, but the password is always invalid (I used a very simple password).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by resetting `/etc/shadow` file permissions which were altered by `root`.