# what happens if all users are set as standard while root password not set

Tags: root, users

I don't dare to do as in the title.
So I set root password first with `sudo passwd root`, and then I change all other users to be standard user, none administrator, so no user can `sudo`.
If I want to set a administrator, just `su root` with the password just set.

But now I wonder what happens if I didn't set root password in the beggining and then change all users to be standard user. Does it mean then this OS cannot be configured by sudoers forever? Is there any method to set new administrator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## What Would Happen

If you configure your system so that no users are administrators, then no one will be able to perform administrative tasks as `root` with [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html) (or its graphical frontends, such as [`gksu`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksu.1.html), [`gksudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksudo.1.html), and [`kdesudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/kdesudo.1.html)) or [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html). Assuming the `root` account remains disabled, you will not be able to log in as `root` (even from a virtual console) or [`su`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/su.1.html)-to-`root` either. Barring possible security vulnerabilities, **this would prevent anyone from performing administrative tasks in the running system.**

## Fixing the Problem

However, if you did this, **the problem would still be easily fixed**, assuming you have physical access to the machine. Fixing this problem is similar to resetting a forgotten password, except you add the user to the `sudo` and/or `admin` groups with [`usermod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/usermod.8.html), rather than resetting their password with [`passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/passwd.5.html).

Here's one method:

1. Boot into recovery mode by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting and selecting it. Select the option for a `root` shell. You'll get a shell with a `#` prompt (rather than the usual `$`). This means it's a `root` shell. Any command you run here is run as `root`.
2. *If you know your username, skip this step.* To find out your username, run `ls /home`. This is a pretty reliable way to list the usernames of the human users of your system (while omitting user accounts like `www-data` and `nobody` which are used internally but don't represent real people).
3. Run these commands to add **`username`** to the necessary group(s) to be an administrator. (Replace **`username`** with the actual username.)

   ```
   usermod -a -G sudo username
   usermod -a -G admin username
   ```

   This separately attempts to add the user to the `sudo` and `admin` groups. In Ubuntu releases up to Ubuntu 11.10, administrators were in the `admin` group. In Ubuntu 12.04 (and in future releases), administrators are in the `sudo` group; if a 12.04 system was upgraded from a previous release, both groups will exist.

   So you can put the user in just one, if you know which one, or you can just run those two commands and put them in whichever exists. I advise doing this with two commands so that if one group doesn't exist, the error doesn't stop `usermod` from attempting to add the user to the other group.

Recovery mode is usually accessible. But occasionally it may be broken, disabled, or require a password, in which case you can boot from a live CD, `chroot` into the installed system, and run the `usermod` commands. Here's a procedure for doing that, adapted from [my considerably more general answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass/147023#147023):

1. If you don't already have one, burn an Ubuntu live CD/DVD (on [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-ubuntu), [Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows), or [Mac OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-mac-osx)) or write an Ubuntu live USB flash drive (on [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu), [Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), or [Mac OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)).
2. In your Ubuntu system (not the live CD/DVD/USB system), run the following command in the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). *You do not need to be an administrator to do this.*

   ```
   mount | grep ' on / '
   ```

   You should include the spaces before `on` and after `/`.
3. That command produces something like `/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)` as the output. The text before `on` (not including the space) is the device name of the partition that contains your Ubuntu system's root filesystem. Remember it (or write it down).
4. Boot the computer from the live CD/DVD/USB and select `Try Ubuntu without installing` (not `Install Ubuntu`).
5. Run these commands, replacing **`/dev/sda1`** with the device name of the partition containing your Ubuntu system's root filesystem, if different (and **`username`** with the name of the user account you wish to give administrative abilities).

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   sudo chroot /mnt
   usermod -a -G sudo username
   usermod -a -G admin username
   exit
   sudo umount /mnt
   ```

   As with the other method, you can use `ls /home` (run this *after* the `chroot` command) to see a list of users on the machine, if you don't know the username.

## Alternatives to Eliminating Administrators

On Ubuntu, when you're an administrator, you still need to authenticate with `sudo` or PolicyKit to perform actions as `root`. This is considered to be at least as secure as using `su` to perform actions as root, since anyone who can compromise your account in such a way to read your own password (for `sudo`) can also read `root`'s password (for `su`). Furthermore, there are some substantial advantages ([explained here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)) of `sudo` over `su`, and enabling the `root` account, while quite possible, is neither recommended nor officially supported in Ubuntu.

If you decide that even though `sudo` and PolicyKit require your password to perform actions as `root`, you still want yourself and all other human users on your machine to run as a standard user (and not as an administrator who can run commands as `root`), you have two easy options:

1. You can **enable the `root` account**, but this is discouraged as explained above. Also, by default you will not be able to log in to a *graphical session* as `root`, and you *should not configure your system to allow this*, as it's particularly dangerous to run an entire graphical desktop environment as `root` (a security bug in any part of it could compromise your system). Also, most GUI programs are not tested as `root` so there may be substantial usability bugs. If you do enable `root`, you should only ever log on as root from a virtual console (or use `su`).
2. The better option is to **just create another user account for administrative purposes.** Make this account an administrator. Having a non-`root` account that can perform administrative tasks with `sudo` and PolicyKit does not force you to use that account for day-to-day, non-administrative tasks.

However, most users are best off with the default--where at least one user account is an administrator and can perform administrative tasks, but must (re)enter their password to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your such detailed reply, I learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you would've had a system with no administrators, but it would be fixable by booting into recovery mode, or using a live session, to edit `/etc/sudoers` and/or `/etc/group`.

Note that setting a password for root is discouraged. Please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: It's discouraged to edit `/etc/group` by hand. You can safely edit `/etc/sudoers` semi-manually with `visudo` (or `visudo -f filename`), which automatically checks your syntax before saving the file. But administrators on an Ubuntu system are administrators because they are in the `sudo` and/or `admin` groups, not by being personally listed in `/etc/sudoers`. Such a listing will enable a user to run commands with `sudo` but will not generally enable them to perform administrative tasks with [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html).

Comment: @gerirha 
Yes, I googled about booting into recovery mode and all the stuff about changing forgotten root password, indeed that is fixable.<br>Also your link about sudo is very nice, thank you.

Comment: @EliahKagan, you are correct that editing /etc/group by hand is not good, but you can use the "vigr" command to edit it safely.  vigr locks the file against other programs (like usermod) that might modify it while you have it in the editor.  There is also a corresponding "vipw" command for editing the passwd file directly.  Both of these commands also accept a "-s" switch for editing the corresponding shadow file.