# Recovering Password

Tags: upgrade, inspiron, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)

My sister gave me her Mini inspiron 1010 with ubuntu 8.04 that she bought in the Philippines more than 3 years ago. The problem is she said she forgot her password so i cant upgrade my ubuntu.

I tried doing this :

1. Boot the mini 9 while pressing ESC every second
2. When you see the "MBR 2FA:" prompt or similar, the boot process is stopped.
3. Press ENTER and ESC very fast one after the other.
4. You should then see the GRUB menu. Using the up and down arrows, highlight the second option and press ENTER to boot into recovery mode.

but nothing happens when i press Enter and Esc nothing happens.

Comment: If you cannot enter recovery mode or single user mode from the boot loader, [you can still reset the password using this method](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass/147023#147023).

Comment: Your best bet is to clean install . It is free and easy. If your "mini" laptop dose not have a CD drive Google for "install ubuntu by USB" you will get loads of results

Comment: @markkirby A clean install would definitely be a good choice, but 8.04 LTS can be upgraded to 10.04 LTS which is still supported, and then it's just one more hop to upgrade to 12.04 LTS (using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` since the first point release isn't out yet).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I have edited appropriately.