# Unable to open Recovery, at boot, using "SHIFT" key (12.04 LTS)

Tags: boot, root, password-recovery

I have tried rebooting multiple times to try to get to "Recovery" (GRUB 2) by holding down "SHIFT" during boot.  I am waiting until BIOS screen completes.  I need to reset the admin password because I forgot it.

Single Ubuntu boot; not dual.  No Windows; one Linux partition.

Comment: it needs to be the left shift key.  sometimes pushing it repeatedly can insure that you don't miss the time window to get the grub menu to appear.

Comment: if all else fails there are answers here that tell you how to use a liveCD to reset, I will try to find one.

Comment: here is a detailed answer on how to use a LiveCd to reset your Admin password.  http://askubuntu.com/a/147023/65969

Comment: Just holding buttons to get into boot time options frequently does not work.  You have to press them repeatedly, and at a savage rate, just when the bios post screens are coming to an end.