# Password recovery - usual options fail

Tags: password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)

Ubuntu 12.04

1) Used the recovery menu to get to a root terminal:

a) mount -o remount,rw / (remounted as rw)

b) passwd my_username (entered new password and confirmed)

c) sync; reboot or exit then resume from menu

d) login fails to recognize password

2) Edited grub menu

a) remove ro and add rw init=/bin/bash

b) simple add rw init=/bin/bash

- login still fails to recognize password, or fails to boot to terminal or gui

3) Used the recovery menu to get to a root terminal:

a) remounted as rw

b) nano -B /etc/shadow

c) removed my username encrypted password so that there would be an empty password for me.

d) reboot

- login still fails to recognize password

4)Used the recovery menu

a) fsck, repair packages, then tried option #1

- login still fails to recognize password

5) Tried the above with a different password rather than the original, in case that was not 'allowed'.

- login still fails to recognize password

By the time anyone answers this I will have reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch, but I'd still like to know what I might have missed that might have worked.

Comment: what is your login shell? how do you know it's not recognising your login? What is the exact error?

Comment: Did you perhaps much about with your pam config? If so, try to undo that. What does /var/log/syslog say about your failed logins?

Comment: [This technique](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass/147023#147023) should work even if the methods you've tried have failed. We might close this as a duplicate of that question; if you try that method and it doesn't work, you can edit this question to provide as much detail as possible, then flag it to request it be reopened.