# I can't remember my password

Tags: password, authentication

My computer goes on standby every 5 minutes and will then request an authentication password; I can't remember setting any password, so I will have to restart the computer again before I can use it. A similar problem occurs whenever I want to upgrade or download software; it keeps asking for authentication password and will not allow me to make any updates. I never set up any authentication password.

Answer (score 2):

When you installed Ubuntu, it usually asks for a User name and a password, a fairly strong password without which it does not proceed ahead with the installation. The system is asking for this password. If you don't remember what the password was, follow the steps given in the answers of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass). There are multiple versions, follow the one applicable to you.