# Password not accepted. How to reset?

Tags: password-recovery

I installed UBUNTU 12.04 LTS today. I had kept my password as "1317kmb".On restarting and updating it asks for password. when i use the above mentioned password, it does not accepts. I don't know why?
How can I reset password.
All my enthusiasm of using UBUNTU has been lost by this.

Comment: You do have an *m* in your password. Can you try `1317k;b` just to check it is not the difference between qwerty and azerty?

Comment: If the above question doesn't help you, please try also this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass

Comment: If this is a keyboards issues, check the active keyboard on the login screen.

Answer (score 2):

You may try typing the password on the user name field to make sure that you are actually entering the correct password.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal window or access the prompt from your grub menu (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword) and type in

```
sudo passwd
```

Enter your password at the prompt and follow the on-screen instructions

***Please Note** When you enter your password and confirm it, nothing is displayed on the screen... It's not your keyboard!*

Comment: How can the OP open a terminal if he cannot login?

Comment: @Private At the grub menu, go to advanced settings then drop back to root. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword