# How to recover the root password on ubuntu server

Tags: server, root, password-recovery

I lost my root/super user password on Ubuntu server.
I tried to boot in a recovery mode and select option `drop to root shell`.

But it is always asks for:

```
Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue)
```

and I don't remember it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try Control-D when it prompts you for the root password. If that doesn't work, then try this:

https://www.howtogeek.com/1287/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/

Then scroll down to "Alternate Root Shell Method".

Comment: Thanks for that, it helped me. It was a little "grub" window different from mine, but i could use it to fix mine. Thanks alot.

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 20, just a few things need changing in the link.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Click [View Console] to access the console and click the send
>      CTRL+ALT+DEL button on the top right. Alternatively, you can also
>      click [RESTART] to restart the server.
> 2. As soon as the boot process starts, press ESC to bring up the GRUB
>      boot prompt. You may need to turn the system off from the control
>      panel and then back on to reach the GRUB boot prompt.
> 3. You will see a GRUB boot prompt - press "e" to edit the first boot
>      option. (If you do not see the GRUB prompt, you may need to press
>      any key to bring it up before the machine boots).
> 4. Find the kernel line (starts with `linux /boot/`) and add
>      `init="/bin/bash"` at the end of the line.
> 5. Press CTRL-X or F10 to boot.
> 6. System will boot and you will see the root prompt. Type `mount -rw
>      -o remount /` and then `passwd` to change the root password and then 
>      reboot again.

Reference: https://www.vultr.com/docs/boot-into-single-user-mode-reset-root-password

Comment: Note that these instructions are specifically about a Vultr cloud server. They may not apply to a local machine running a standard Ubuntu image, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you are using it on a local machine you have to start it with step 3 and onwards, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

There is no root password in Ubuntu.  This is a security feature:  it's impossible to log in as root, no password means there is no password that can be cracked.

When prompted for the password in recovery mode, just hit [enter].

Comment: I know i can't log in as a root, i meant the administrator account of mine, i forgot it. 

and bout the root, when it asks me for the password, i did put to the role "root" a password, i don't remember it either!!

Comment: I can't login as root to a desktop, but in case of server "which i am asking for" it is normal to login as a root!.

Comment: It's not impossible to log in as root...