# How To Reset The Ubuntu server Password

Tags: server, password-recovery

I lost My Ubuntu Server password and I don't know what to do.
So I posted this question on AskUbuntu

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/395196/how-to-recover-the-root-password-on-ubuntu-server?rq=1

Comment: @muzzafar: Every time I have to approve an edit of yours, I have extra work reviewing it again... Please review my last edits to your edit and please turn on the spell checker in your browser.  We appreciate your edits, but take just 20 seconds more every time and don't just add the tags, but correct the spelling, grammar and readability of the questions as well!  ;-)  Thanks for your work so far!  ;-)
(*Edit:* and whether the question has an answer already too would be fantastic!)
P.S. I'm not a native English speaker neither.

Comment: OK, I will try best to improve edits.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the password using single user mode.

Check the below link for help

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword