# Assistance Needed: Recovering Root Password and Accessing Firewall Settings on Ubuntu 20.04 Server

Tags: networking, server, password, firewall

I am encountering issues with my Ubuntu 20.04 server running on Oracle, as I have forgotten the root password. Unfortunately, I am unable to access the GRUB menu to initiate password recovery. Could you please provide guidance on how to reset the root password under these circumstances?

Additionally, I mistakenly closed the firewall, which is now preventing me from accessing the aapanel panel. Is there a way to modify the firewall settings without requiring root privileges?

Your assistance in resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover the root password on ubuntu server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395196/how-to-recover-the-root-password-on-ubuntu-server)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)