# Setting password for administrator

Tags: password, administrator

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have three users - one administrator and two standard users. I changed the password for administrator to 'None'. Later I used `passwd` command to set the password for the same user. But the password is not getting set.

Comment: See [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/22949) and (if that doesn't help) [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/121698/22949)

Answer (score 1):

Boot from live CD.

Mount the / partition.

Chroot to the mounted partition

Assign a password to your account to activate it.

### Details:

You’ll want to boot from your Ubuntu Live CD, choosing “Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer” from the boot menu.

Once the system boots, open up a new Terminal window from Applications \ Accessories and then type in the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This command is used to tell what device name the hard drive is using, which in most cases should be /dev/sda1, but could be different on your system.
[image]

Now you’ll need to create a directory to mount the hard drive on. Since we’re actually booting off the live cd, the directory doesn’t really get created anywhere.

```
sudo mkdir /media/sda1
```

The next command will mount the hard drive in the /media/sda1 folder.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1
```

Now it’s time for the command that actually does the magic: chroot.

```
sudo chroot /media/sda1
```

Now you should be able to use the passwd command to change your user account’s password, and it will be applied to the hard drive since we are using chroot.

```
passwd ADMINUSER
```

Note that you’ll have to type your username after the passwd command in order to change the right password.

Now you should be able to reboot your system and log yourself in with your new password.