# Lost password, recovery mode doesn't help

Tags: login, password, recovery-mode

A friend of mine has a old Ubuntu laptop that he wants to put back into use, but since it has been some time since he used it he has forgotten his password.

I've looked up how to change but none of them will work. I have also tried using the recovery mode, but using the root mode is locked also and requires a password. (We can not reformat the disk due to some pictures on it.)

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Please read through [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass) question.

Comment: See this answer from Oli http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password?435347#435347

Answer (score 2):

You can boot the laptop with a live CD and `chroot` into the system and then change the password of any user. I have made this with the minimal installation CD from Gentoo.

- Download this ISO image (or Ubuntu Live CD) and burn it or make boot-able USB with:

  http://distfiles.gentoo.org/releases/amd64/autobuilds/current-iso/install-amd64-minimal-20140313.iso
- You need to find out the partitions on the old laptop. Assuming that you have an IDE hard drive with only root, boot and swap partitions you do this

  ```
  mount /dev/hda3 /mnt/gentoo/
  mount /dev/hda1 /mng/gentoo/boot
  swapon /dev/hda2
  ```
- Then you need to mount proc,dev and sys

  ```
  mount -t proc proc /mnt/gentoo/proc
  mount --rbind /dev /mnt/gentoo/dev
  mount --rbind /sys /mnt/gentoo/sys
  ```
- Then you chroot

  ```
  chroot /mnt/gentoo /bin/bash
  ```

After this you can change your password with `passwd`

I hope this help