# forgot password for another one user account created in my system, how to solve it?

Tags: password-recovery

I have two user accounts and forgot one user's password. I have tried to reset it from the boot menu. After selecting recovery mode I have selected Drop to root shell prompt option but then it asked me to "give the root password for maintenance(or type control-D to continue)" don't know the password and even typing control-D doesn't work

What should I do now??

Please give me a solution

Comment: OK, I'll remove my answer for now, have to save my laptop first :). If no one jumps in , I'll be back later.

Comment: In the meantime, did you see this post? http://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass/147023#147023

Comment: and many others on Askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=recover+password

Comment: does the user you still have access to have root privileges?

Comment: @Minos no it doesn't.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm i'll look at the posts and try it.thnx

Answer (score 0):

Login with the user where you still know the password.
Open a terminal and get a root shell, e.g. `sudo -i`.

Then change the password for the user you don't know the password:

```
passwd username
```

Replace username with the name of your user.

Afterwards close the the root shell with *Strg+D*
and test with `su - username` the new password.

Comment: the OP stated in his/her comments that they do not have root access, either in recovery mode or via sudo. Thi shas to be resolved with a live CD and is a duplicate with a link to the solution given above.