# I can't get into the sudoers listings

Tags: command-line, sudo, gimp

I try to type a command, to get Pinta (because GIMP isn't here for some odd reason)

> (Command is sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu),

and it says

> asbell is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I didn't find a way to solve my issue. Thanks though.

Comment: Pretty much all of them.

Comment: Well, in the midst of number one, my computer froze and stopped working. When I tried number two, it said I have to be root to access anything. When I tried number three, it said only Root is allowed to put you into the sudoers listings

Comment: Please *edit your question*, with *as many details as possible.* (Please include the complete and exact text of any error messages.) Note also that answers don't always appear in the same order--but this will be addressed if you describe the steps you took. From what you've said, it sounds like [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/147023) should work for you (you'll probably have to read the whole thing, but note especially the part that says "Alternatively, if you want to make a user an administrator"). But that method is long and complicated compared to others you might still be able to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the CD, my older brother does, along with many others used on other systems, and I lack a blank one. I will edit the information, though.

Comment: What do you see when you run the command `groups`?