# Don't know password, how do I set a new one?

Tags: password, reset

I have been using UbuntuLKB 17 for almost half a year now, and recently, when attempting to download updates, am prompted for a password. I never set a password for Ubuntu. I've read similar threads on this sight telling me where to go via terminal to simply set a new one, but I can't do any of this without entering the current password, which I don't know.
Help? Thanks.

Comment: Some of the methods detailed in [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/22949) should still work. See also [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/121698/22949) (what you've described here seems to resemble the specific situation there).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a recovery boot option. Don't know your version, you may need to insert install media and do renovery boot. This gives a root shell. Mount your lost-password-file-system to a new folder. Use the chroot command. Then just use passwd as normal, because your root it'll run smoothly.