# reinstall ubuntu or delete the root password without having it?

Tags: grub2, password, root, password-recovery, recovery-mode

I have received a laptop from school but i can't download anything because there is a root password on it.

I already used the GRUB screen by clicking on the shift button but the '(recovery mode)' line isn't in the menu.

Is there a way to reinstall ubuntu or delete the root password without having it?

Comment: The other techniques described in [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/22949) should still work. See also [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/121698/22949)

Answer (score 2):

If indicated by Harris, it does not work try:

Download Ubuntu iso image.

Burn it to a Dvd or Usb.

Start Computer / reboot computer.

Make sure BIOS is set to boot from Dvd/Usb

Put your Ubuntu Live-Dvd/Usb

Now booting will start from Ubuntu Live-Dvd/Usb

You will see two option screen - select Try it

You will system is booting in to Live-session

Open a terminal

Find out your root partition

```
sudo su
fdisk -l
```

Suppose it is /dev/sda1, run the following commands:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
```

Note: Replace /dev/sda1, for its partition.

Chroot is an operation that changes the apparent root directory (live-session) for the current running process (hard disk installation).

Now you can change the root password:

```
passwd
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

If you want to change password for Ubuntu user:

```
passwd user-name
```

Comment: but because the laptop is locked by school i can't use commands on terminal with 'sudo' ...

Comment: @pleasureguy You can use `sudo` commands freely in a Live session (which you get by booting from DVD/USB)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the existing boot entry to replace `quiet splash` with `recovery nomodeset`. In grub, you need to press e to go into edit mode and after editing F10 to boot.