# Unable to reboot into recovery mode and reset password

Tags: password, recovery-mode

Someone else installed ubuntu on my laptop, as a result i dont have the admin password. i'm unable to do anything without it. so i googled it, found some procedures and tried to follow that. but unfortunately i'm unable to boot into recovery mode, i tried holding down the [shift] key, but as soon as i press the power button to start my laptop, ubuntu logo comes faster than light and it takes me straight into the home. i also see a message when booting "booting into insecure mode". what am i supposed to do now? i have never used linux before, so i have no idea what to do. how to reset the password now? is there any other method? any kind of help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Without telling us which instructions you followed it will be difficult to help take a look at this question: [How do I reset a lost password](http://askubuntu.com/q/121698/107450).  If the instructions there or at the linked question don't work tell us exactly when it's going wrong.

Comment: Rather than shift, tap the up/down arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

1. do you have any information on the the laptop that you wish to preserve/save?

   - **if you don't**, best thing to do would be to reinstall. This way, you will get to know a little more about Ubuntu/linux and I can assure you, it is not hard at all! 
     Installing Ubuntu these days is **very** easy.
2. try pressing the shift key repeatedly instead of holding-it.
3. if the disk/home folder is not encrypted you could recover your data in different ways like:

   - putting the disk in another PC/laptop as an additional disk
   - putting the disk in a portable rack (enclosure) and connect through usb/e-sata
   - etc.
4. if the question is how you can bypass the password, i don't think anyone here will help :)

Comment: Actually, recovery mode *does not* require a password.