# Accidentally took execute privileges off my /home

Tags: sudo

Afterwards I couldn't execute any commands without receiving a 'permission denied' error.

Upon restarting the computer, when I enter my password Ubuntu will look like it's loading for a second but return to the password prompt over and over.

What I did:

1. Entered root by typing `sudo -i`
2. Entered my password
3. I was trying to edit permissions in my /home folder but I think I changed the wrong directory. I did a `chmod -R -x` and now my /home has no execute permissions.
4. Typed `su tom`
5. Couldn't execute any commands or log in.

When I tried to type even the simplest command such as `cd` I was given a permission denied error.

I can't log into my tom user, so I'm on a guest account and don't have access to sudo. When I try to `cd /home` I get the error *bash: cd: /home: Permission denied*

Comment: if my answer is not sufficient, you need to post exactly what it says in the terminal to indicate to you that it is broken. thanks

Comment: You will have to be more specific than saying things like "didn't work" and "broken".

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I edited the question a bit. Right now I can't log into my tom user and it seems to have lost its password.

Comment: If you ran that command on / you will have to reinstall. Boot to recovery mode and try to fix permissions in home.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I can go into all other folders but my /home

Comment: boot to recovery mode, remount your / or /home partition rw, and run find http://z9.io/2013/11/05/fix-file-644-directory-775-permissions-linux-easily/

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, do I need to run the `chmod -R +X` command as well or just the finds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [bodhi.zazen says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605425/accidentally-took-execute-privileges-off-my-home#comment846433_605425), you should boot to recovery mode and change the permissions back. Recovery mode should still work fine--this change is unlikely to render it unusable--but if for any reason you cannot use recovery mode, you can use a live CD/DVD/USB.

Hold down shift while booting so the GRUB menu is shown. Select *Advanced options for Ubuntu*, then select the first entry whose name ends in *(recovery mode)*. Then on the recovery menu, select the option labeled:

```
root              Drop to root shell prompt
```

This should give you a `#` root shell prompt. Remount your [`/` filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory) readwrite by running:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

(Note that you don't need `sudo` for that--nor for the `chmod` commands below--because you are already in a root shell, provided to you by recovery mode.)

Assuming the only changes you made were to execute permissions, you can then simply run:

```
chmod a+x /home
chmod -R u+X /home/tom
```

`+X` sets execute permissions specifically when a file is already executable by some user *or a directory* (see [`man chmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/chmod.1.html) for details; note that capital `+X` is different from `+x`, which always sets execute permissions). [On directories, execute permissions confer the ability to go into the directory.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#Folder.2FDirectory_Permissions) Losing that ability appears to be what has effectively locked you out of your account.

- Since you *just* took away executable permissions, there's *no need* to walk the directory hierarchy with a more complicated [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/find.1.html) command and [identify each file by type to change their permissions](http://z9.io/2013/11/05/fix-file-644-directory-775-permissions-linux-easily/). Running `chmod` recursively with `+X` will make all the directories "executable" (i.e., enterable) by their owner again, which is precisely what you need here. (There's nothing really *wrong* with a `find`-based method, such as the one presented in [tfmertz's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/605454/22949)--either way will work fine by itself. And if you happened to do both, what's fine too.)

Then boot normally, either by running `reboot` or by running `exit` (which brings you back to the recovery menu) and selecting the *resume* option.

Those `chmod` commands won't necessarily put things back to *exactly* what they were before--for that, it would probably be necessary to see what command you ran (but you may be able to find that by running `history` after logging back in). However, this will likely be sufficient to enable you to log in and use your Ubuntu system normally again.

*This situation, and the solution, is similar to the more common situation where the sole administrator of a system has lost their password. Thus, while you're changing permissions rather than a password and the solution is not exactly the same, you might find it useful to take a look at [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) Some of the answers there contain screenshots showing how to get a root shell from recovery mode. And if you are unable to access recovery mode, the instructions there (and in [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)) about accessing your system from a live CD/DVD/USB should help.*

Comment: I ran the find commands that @bodhi.zazen linked, hopefully those will work? Right now I am fully functional again, but I'm not sure what permissions still differ from their original settings.

Comment: @tfmertz Yes, that should work fine. `chmod`ing with capital `+X` or using `find` commands to identify directories and set them executable will both work to enable you to go into your directories again (they'll both reverse the change made by `chmod`ing everything with `-x`). Either way works by itself but if you happened already to have done both, that's fine too.

Answer (score 1):

The /home folder needs to have its execute permission restored

1. Restart Ubuntu
2. Run recovery mode in root ([Recovery mode how to](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode))
3. Run the find commands to restore permissions

#### Resetting /home permissions

Run both the commands below found from [z9.io](http://z9.io/2013/11/05/fix-file-644-directory-775-permissions-linux-easily/)

> For directories only do this
>
> `find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`
>
> For files only do this.
>
> `find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;`

Restart Ubuntu in normal mode and try to log in.

Answer (score 0):

More than an answer is just a comment about this same issue it happened to me just a few minutes back (Jan 26 2016) where I was completing a lab and I entered a chmod 600 ~ command, so I lost access to my home, so I came to this article, and first tried the find commands and the terminal started reading everything, but it all ended in a permission denied result. 
I went ahead and tried the: 
chmod a+x /home
chmod -R u+X /home/myname

and that resolved it immediately. I was able to start entering cd again.