# reset root password

Tags: boot

I have a computer that has Ubuntu as the OS.  I don't get a LILO screen and the computer boots straight from the BIOS to the GUI.  I don't know how to get the terminal window.  I don't know what the previous owner changed the ROOT password to, and apparently he changed ROOT to USER because it is listed in users as the administrator.  Is there a way to reset Linux to the out of the box settings or do I need a startup disk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the <kbd>F8</kbd> key usually shows the boot menu. Once in boot menu enter <kbd>E</kbd> to edit. Then in the line which says quiet splash append the following:

```
init=/bin/sh
```

Then continue to boot by pressing <kbd>B</kbd>. You will be logged in as the root user. From there enter the commands:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
passwd
```

Then enter the new root password and reboot the system.