# pasted "init 0" in /etc/rc.local!

Tags: startup, init, etc

I tried if this works on my friends computer and you know what happened.
Please help me fix the computer executing "`init 0`" as root on startup..
Help me fix this and retrieve my OS back... intact... as it was!

Comment: Did you try to enter in recovery mode and fix it back to level 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enter in recovery mode. Start the machine and when the BIOS passes press (hold) <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. (Once the Ubuntu logo appears you have missed it. Do it again.) When Grub appears select "Advanced Options" and then select the line where you see something like "recovery mode". After while few options will appear. Select "Drop to root shell prompt". Partition will be mounted in "read" state. Write

`mount -o remount,rw /`

into the shell to remount it in "read-write" mode. You can change the /etc/rc.local back to level 2 with some Terminal editor (nano?). Be carefull in recovery mode not to make more damage! If you need to mount the home partition write

`mount --all`

**after** remounting the root partition.

Booting into recovery mode [reference](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

Comment: that saved my job!

Comment: what if i did'nt know the root password? Would you be able to still save my job?

Comment: If you selected "Drop to root shell prompt" after entering into recovery mode, it shouldn't ask for password. You can even change the root password there.

Comment: it asked me for the root password... no kidding

Comment: Hmm...It should not...I do not know if this can have something to do with changing root pass before. ex: if the root pass was changed with "sudo passwd" instead with only "passwd" when loged in as root. Anyhow...I will try when I come home from work.

Comment: Found this...http://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass ... your job can still be saved!