# Root shell in recovery mode unusable on Mac (16.10 Desktop)

Tags: grub2, keyboard-layout, 16.10, recovery-mode

I tried to use recovery mode as follows:

- Restart, holding Shift
- In GRUB menu, select Advanced Options, then `Ubuntu, with Linux 4.8.0-34-generic (recovery mode)`
- Press enter to get the root shell prompt

Now I cannot type certain characters, such as `w` or `x`.

I suppose the keyboard layout got selected wrongly, but how to fix this?

One idea was to press `e` before selecting the recovery mode to **edit** the launch commands. But I do not know what to do here. I hope someone can enlighten me on how to set a generic functioning keyboard here, or suggest another solution.

*PS: This was originally posted because of a lost password. I fixed this with a clean reinstall. But the original problem with the unusable recovery mode is still there.*

Comment: Is it possible your keyboard isn't working right in Ubuntu when it boots normally either, and that's why your password isn't accepted? Other thoughts... Though your recovery mode woes aren't the same, you should be able to reset your password by `chroot`ing in from a live environment. See [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/121698) You may still want to find out why recovery mode doesn't work and fix it, so you can use it in the future. But if your only goal is to reset your password, that should enable you to do so.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help because I cannot mount the file system (read-only warning, errors).  Yes, I would like to solve the more fundamental recovery mode issue.