# Ubuntu password

Tags: password, user-management

Yesterday bought an Asus Vivo Notebook with Ubuntu pre-loaded. The password was set to the store. At home, I just changed the name from the store to my own. I went through the software then switched off.

Today my screen is stuck on my name, wanting a password that I do not have. How do I change or add a user? None of the youtube vids work. I can't access the reboot program either.

Comment: Was this a new device with Ubuntu installed on it? (the release of Ubuntu, and/or flavor is also useful to knowing password) though new machines are usually OEM installs where you enter the username & password (not pre-configured).  Was it a recycler? (second hand device) as they can use their own builds with their own password (*I've volunteered at such a store, we gave out documentation which contained username & password*)

Comment: How did you change the name? Didn't that ask your for a password? In any case, the simplest solution is to just call the store and ask them. Have you tried that?

Comment: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password), [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass), and [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user) (which also works even if you're using a user account that has never previously had the ability to use sudo) should help.