# Reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 from USB

Tags: boot, usb, password-recovery

I managed to ruin the password so I want to completely reinstall Ubuntu 20.04. I have 'ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso' on a USB stick but when I try to boot from it I'm told the boot file/s can't be found.

I can't use 'sudo' because of the password problem and I've tried several ways to restore privileges to no avail.

Will I need to format the drive in order to reinstall Ubuntu?

Alan

Comment: If your Ubuntu system is ***not*** encrypted, I think this link will answer your question: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: *"I've tried several ways to restore privileges to no avail."* Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot how to make a bootable drive. You'll need another operating system to do so, download software such as Balena Etcher or Rufus and select the `.iso` file to make a bootable drive. And try to follow some tutorial on youtube on "how to make a bootable drive" such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqTtt7ljUWQ)
one .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Rufus didn't work but I was able to use 'universal-usb-installer'. You put me on the right track and I eventually found what I needed. And it worked!

Alan