# I changed my user password, but now i can't login. What can i do?

Tags: login, password, reset

a few minutes ago I changed my Ubuntu user password. Then I turned off the computer and turned it on. After I entered the new password, the system would tell me that the password was wrong. I tried to enter the old password, but without success. Now, I can't log into my computer and I can't even reset my password. What can I do?

Comment: I would try [resetting the password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) again, this time being extra cautious.

Comment: Try with small and capitals reversed. In all other cases: reset the password from a root prompt (grub rescue or a live session).

Comment: *"Now, I can't log into my computer and I can't even reset my password."* If the answers at at [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/22949) are not working for you, see also [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/121698/22949)

Comment: Another thing to try is the numlock key -- there is no warning when that is on, and some keyboards get some letters changed to numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do it from recovery mode.**

> Reboot from lock screen.
>
> Press <kbd>esc</kbd> while rebooting.
>
> Go to <kbd>Advanced Options for Ubuntu</kbd>.
>
> Go to <kbd>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.##-generic (recovery mode)</kbd>.
>
> Got to <kbd>root</kbd>.
>
> Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.
>
> Now execute the following commands...

**Remount root with write access.**

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

> It should not output anything.

**List users.**

```
ls /home
```

> Remember your username from the list.

**Change your password.**

```
passwd your_username
```

> Type your new password and Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Exit the terminal.**

```
exit
```

> Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! You resolved my issue!

Comment: Now I have one question, would you consider it as a vulnerability?

Comment: It is not vulnerability as it can be used only while having physical access to the computer.

Comment: True, but you can't do it on iOS for example. So does it make Ubuntu less secure than iOS? _(I know I shouldn't compare it with iOS but I'm doing just for the sake of examples)_

Comment: I am not experienced with iOS, but in general as long as the attacker has physical access to the device, there is always a way he can get in. (Assuming the attacker is skilled enough).