# How do I install Ubuntu on my computer (Lenovo with Intel N3700 1.6GHz X4 64b) with its 17.04 Ubuntu where passwords have been forgotten?

Tags: system-installation

How do I install Ubuntu on my computer (Lenovo with Intel N3700 1.6GHz  X4 64b) with its 17.04 Ubuntu where passwords have been forgotten? I have tried several times to create a new password using online instructions without success. Please answer, if there is any hope of ever using my PC again. If the answer is that I cannot, then I am forced to take my PC to the dump! Your response will be appreciated.

David

Comment: The simplest option would be to [make a bootable USB of 20.04 or 21.04](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview), wipe your partitions clear, then start from zero.

Comment: Install from scratch, end of story. If you need to recover personal files from the old installation you need the password, period. Even if you can reset it (in a non-encrypted installation) you won't be able to access the old files, that's why we use passwords and, at an higher security level, encryption. If we could simply reset passwords there wouldn't be a point in using them, don't you think? So, again, just install a supported Ubuntu release, forget about the old one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 or the 2017-April release is EOL (*end-of-life*). https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/01/17/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus-reached-end-of-life-on-january-13-2018/   Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades but note it's no longer supported on this site due to EOL status (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

You can just re-install Ubuntu but your question is rather unclear as it's missing details.

Re-installation doesn't require the old passwords, as your new passwords will replace the old (system directories get erased so old passwords will be deleted), **HOWEVER** if you used **encryption** all data will be lost.

You can install without loosing any data; just manually select existing partitions (ie. use *Something-else/Manual/Manual Partitioning*), ensure they are **not** selected for format, and the install process will

- note packages you have manually installed
- erase system directories
- install new system
- add back the additional packages you had added to your system (if available for your new release from Ubuntu repositories)
- ask you to reboot

No user file is touched unless you selected 'format'.

This assumes a desktop system (*server programs often store config files in system directories; those are lost*), and no encryption is involved. This process can be done with encrypted disks too, however you'll need to know the keys or else format (thus loosing data).

This will allow you to use a supported system, instead of your [EOL 17.04 system](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/01/17/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus-reached-end-of-life-on-january-13-2018/)

Comment: FYI:   I last QA-tested this install on an *impish* or what will be 21.10 install only yesterday; I rotate my QA-test passwords & had no idea what password I had used on the prior install (about 5 days prior), but the password doesn't matter to re-install, or in your case *upgrade via re-install*.   (My install was Lubuntu, but that makes no difference as the install works with Ubuntu and *flavors* of Ubuntu too)

Comment: I have tried many times to reinstall my Ubuntu 17.04, so that I could create new passwords, but I have been unable to get detailed information on how to actually perform the operation. If I try the terminal, I am asked for a SUDO password which I have lost years ago. If I try the Firefox browser, it asks for a password to install new software. I am not learned enough to proceed.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 is EOL so we cannot answer questions about it sorry (EOL, ESM or *development* releases are off-topic here). This answer is about replacing it with another on-topic release such as 20.04, or 21.04