# Forgot sudo password, can't get to grub on boot, can't boot from USB

Tags: kubuntu, sudo, root

I don't mind wiping all data.

I have looked up similar issues but can't really find anyone in my situation. Many answers assume I can enter grub menu, others assume you can access the live USB, and others assume you have a password for root. I can't do any of those three. I have had this problem for a year.

I'm running Kubuntu.
When I try to boot from the live USB to reinstall latest Kubuntu 22.04, I get this error, even though I haven't got a floppy disk on this PC.

[image: Grub floppy error]

I have the password of the only of user in the system if that helps, but it is not on the sudoers group. And I keep getting the message this incident will be reported. By now I don't know if I have ever set up a password for root or if I have forgotten it. I'm not dual booting in this machine.
I can't access grub menu either since when I press Shift or Esc on booting, grub menu is not displayed.

Since I can't access sudo, I can't update the system.

This is the boot menu.

[image: This is the boot menu.]

I don't know which of these option to choose to boot from the live USB.

[image: I don't know which of these option to choose to boot from the live USB]

Comment: The screen images you've attached are not Ubuntu screens, but hardware/firmware specific, and the Ubuntu OS cannot overrule hardware specifics.  You must get past your *firmware* screens to allow a Ubuntu/Kubuntu system to boot.  This is a Ubuntu Q&A site & not a hardware/firmware Q&A site.

Comment: I can boot on Kubuntu with no issue getting past the hardware screens, the only problem is I can't access root once I am on Kubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)

Comment: I wish it did but those assume they can access the live CD or GRUB I can't access none, let me try the last answer in that post though

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by your question, since you paste *firmware* screens that are not involved in Ubuntu (*being hardware specific & relate to before any OS including Kubuntu is booted*), and have no idea what you mean by Grub Floppy Error (*I still have devices here with floppy drives, and many without - but have never seen any such error so have no idea what you're asking about*).  A link to a picture of the error may resolve that for me, but hopefully others will know what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I have uploaded that floppy error screenshot

Comment: Thanks for posting the GRUB FLOPPY ERROR ..   I can't recall seeing it before, however a scan online seems to indicate that your machine *firmware* (ie. device) thinks you have a FLOPPY device plugged into a USB port thus has told the OS there is one attached..  You likely do not have a USB-Floppy-drive connected, but have some other USB device that was *cheapily put together* and the creator was not careful of the device message, thus a keyboard/mouse/usb-hub/(anything-plugged-into-your-USB) reports wrongly to your system that's its a floppy drive. To remove that error unplug that device

Comment: As you won't *likely* know what device it is; you may need to unplugging USB devices until it's gone... unless the details I got online were incorrect...   After that error message, the subsequent lines were from your machine firmware (ie. Boot from CD/DVD then Disk Boot Failure).. but the `grub` message highlights GRUB at least tried to boot in my opinion meaning...   My 2c (*having no experience with the error myself such it's what I found online only*)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144863/discussion-between-kepol-and-guiverc).

Comment: Sorry, I access this site using my Ubuntu SSO (Ubuntu signon) and chat requires me to login to Stack Exchange (*I'm not logged into Stack Exchange, accessing the site only via Ubuntu login*).  I can't access Chat using my Ubuntu signon.

Comment: Ok I am using a different live USB now that it works on a different machine, not getting the floppy grub error  but not managing to boot onto the live USB  either , I will try different USB ports and put the right booting instruction

Comment: from this screenshot,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKdEr.jpg what option do I choose to boot into the live USB? @guiverc

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I managed to reinstall Kubuntu wiping everything. I had to go into bios, change the first device to boot to USB-ZIP.
First try the live Usb in a different PC to make sure it worked, since the first one was causing Floppy GRUB error.