# How To Reset Ubuntu Password?

Tags: 14.04, 22.04, password, hacking

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. today i tried to change my ubuntu password and then i tried to unlock it and when i tried i got to know that i forgot the password . i tried to find solution and i got https://itsfoss.com/how-to-hack-ubuntu-password/. i tried the 1st solution given on the website then i successfully opened the ubuntu but it was not a solution because it was asking to unlock the ubuntu like unlock to add users and change settings

Comment: The tag 14.04 makes this off topic. Why both 14.04 and 22.04 tags?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass  and or https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.