# my user pssword has been chnged

Tags: permissions

I use a stand alone desktop running ubuntu 22.04. The admin password has been changed (hacked). How do I regain control as my password is no longer accepted, and I can not use sudo, or choose a new password in user settings? I have tried a posted solution using recovery options and root shell, but despite following instructions carefully, my attempt was unsuccessful.
In addition, I am unable to install security updates. I located a number of trojan horse viruses using clamshell and have quarantined them.

Comment: see [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)

Comment: and if you did not do it:  Changing the password is not enough... you need to reinstall your system.