# Login Loop after Power Failure (/home on separate partition)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, login, fsck

I am working on a Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series laptop which is dual booted for Ubuntu 22.04 and Window 11. **The /sda5 partition contains the OS while /sda10 partition was for /home. Windows is working fine.**

The problem started with a **power loss**. I skipped the disk check on restart as I was in hurry. However, we lost the power again. **The restart blinked on disk check and immediately went to command line “need root password for maintenance”.** I tried sudo user password which did not work. After sometime, login screen appeared and I found myself stuck in login loop.
Steps taken by me till now: -

1. I made a live USB and found that data on `/sda10` is fine while `/sda5/home` was empty (/home was /sda10). [Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7gNd.png)
2. Using the excellent comment by Eliah Kagan https://askubuntu.com/a/147023/491560 here I created a root password.
3. I tried `fsck -y /dev/sda5` and `fsck -A -y /dev/sda5` which did not show any result.
4. I rebooted and provided my newly created root password. It led me to command line screen where even fsck was not possible. Login Loop still persisted.
5. I used Live USB again and created **a new user ‘rec’** with sudo privilege. This got an entry in /home directory.
6. I tried `e2fsck -yf /dev/sda5`. It actually processed.
7. On returning to normal login, Login Loop still exists for newly created ‘rec’ user.
8. I got following details when I checked the grub edit. `setparams 'Ubuntu...' recordfail set gxfpayload... insmod part_msdos insmod ext2 set root=... search --no-floppy... linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38... initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6....`
9. The memtest is giving *kernel shim error*.
10. The `df -Th` command doesn’t show /sda10 or window partition. **Gparted shows all.**

The /sda5 and /sda10 partition was not created by me.  I was getting some BIOS bugs but system is working fine. I can’t update BIOS as it requires laptop battery.

I have some online programs running. Due to my work, reformatting /sda5 is my last option.

Ask anything more that may be needed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: 'cat fstab' shows error in /sda5.   'journalctl -p 4 -b 0' shows insufficient permission.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

Since the whole problem started due to  power failure; I searched that as query. One of most common suggested reason was / switching to protection mode.

So, basically my root / went into read-only mode.

1. `cat /etc/fstab` gave me remount-ro error.
2. To be sure I performed normal disk check `fsck -f /dev/sda5`
3. Next to isolate bad sectors (if any) `e2fsck -fccky /dev/sda5 #`
4. Reboot
5. `mount -o remount,rw /` to give read-write permission to OS drive.
6. Back to normal.
7. `smartctl -t long /dev/sda` and `smartmontool' need to be done to check disk.