# Not able to install using apt-get after changing username

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I recently changed username of my ubuntu account to "admin", earlier it used to be "sunbeam". Now I'm trying to install pylint using apt-get, but I'm getting the following error

```
admin@inspiron-5567:~$ sudo apt-get install pylint
[sudo] password for admin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  blt libtcl8.6 libtk8.6 python-astroid python-backports.functools-lru-cache python-concurrent.futures python-configparser python-egenix-mxdatetime python-egenix-mxtools python-isort python-lazy-object-proxy
  python-logilab-common python-mccabe python-setuptools python-singledispatch python-tk python-wrapt tk8.6-blt2.5
Suggested packages:
  blt-demo tcl8.6 tk8.6 pylint-doc python-egenix-mxdatetime-dbg python-egenix-mxdatetime-doc python-egenix-mxtools-dbg python-egenix-mxtools-doc pyro python-unittest2 python-setuptools-doc tix python-tk-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  blt libtcl8.6 libtk8.6 pylint python-astroid python-backports.functools-lru-cache python-concurrent.futures python-configparser python-egenix-mxdatetime python-egenix-mxtools python-isort
  python-lazy-object-proxy python-logilab-common python-mccabe python-setuptools python-singledispatch python-tk python-wrapt tk8.6-blt2.5
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,667 kB of archives.
After this operation, 21.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libtcl8.6 libtk8.6 tk8.6-blt2.5 blt python-lazy-object-proxy python-wrapt python-singledispatch python-backports.functools-lru-cache python-setuptools python-astroid python-concurrent.futures python-isort
  python-mccabe python-configparser python-logilab-common pylint python-egenix-mxtools python-egenix-mxdatetime python-tk
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Get:1 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  libtcl8.6 8.6.8+dfsg-3 [881 kB]
Err:1 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  libtcl8.6 8.6.8+dfsg-3
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/libtcl8.6_8.6.8+dfsg-3_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:2 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  libtk8.6 8.6.8-4 [693 kB]
Err:2 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  libtk8.6 8.6.8-4
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/libtk8.6_8.6.8-4_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:3 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  tk8.6-blt2.5 2.5.3+dfsg-4 [572 kB]
Err:3 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  tk8.6-blt2.5 2.5.3+dfsg-4
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/tk8.6-blt2.5_2.5.3+dfsg-4_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:4 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  blt 2.5.3+dfsg-4 [4,944 B]
Err:4 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  blt 2.5.3+dfsg-4
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/blt_2.5.3+dfsg-4_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:5 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-lazy-object-proxy 1.3.1-1 [20.8 kB]
Err:5 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-lazy-object-proxy 1.3.1-1
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-lazy-object-proxy_1.3.1-1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:6 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-wrapt 1.9.0-3 [27.5 kB]
Err:6 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-wrapt 1.9.0-3
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-wrapt_1.9.0-3_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:7 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-singledispatch 3.4.0.3-2 [9,848 B]
Err:7 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-singledispatch 3.4.0.3-2
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-singledispatch_3.4.0.3-2_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:8 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-backports.functools-lru-cache 1.4-2 [5,960 B]
Err:8 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-backports.functools-lru-cache 1.4-2
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-backports.functools-lru-cache_1.4-2_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:9 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-setuptools 39.0.1-2 [329 kB]
Err:9 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-setuptools 39.0.1-2
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-setuptools_39.0.1-2_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:10 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-astroid 1.6.0-1 [108 kB]
Err:10 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-astroid 1.6.0-1
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-astroid_1.6.0-1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:11 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-concurrent.futures 3.2.0-1 [34.2 kB]
Err:11 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-concurrent.futures 3.2.0-1
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-concurrent.futures_3.2.0-1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:12 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-isort 4.3.4+ds1-1 [30.4 kB]
Err:12 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-isort 4.3.4+ds1-1
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-isort_4.3.4+ds1-1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:13 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-mccabe 0.6.1-2 [8,092 B]
Err:13 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-mccabe 0.6.1-2
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-mccabe_0.6.1-2_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:14 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-configparser 3.5.0-1 [59.6 kB]
Err:14 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-configparser 3.5.0-1
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-configparser_3.5.0-1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:15 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-logilab-common 1.4.1-1 [369 kB]
Err:15 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-logilab-common 1.4.1-1
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-logilab-common_1.4.1-1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:16 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  pylint 1.8.3-1 [342 kB]
Err:16 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  pylint 1.8.3-1
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/pylint_1.8.3-1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:17 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-egenix-mxtools 3.2.9-1 [75.3 kB]
Err:17 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-egenix-mxtools 3.2.9-1
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-egenix-mxtools_3.2.9-1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:18 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-egenix-mxdatetime 3.2.9-1 [68.3 kB]
Err:18 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-egenix-mxdatetime 3.2.9-1
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-egenix-mxdatetime_3.2.9-1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:19 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-tk 2.7.15~rc1-1 [25.9 kB]
Err:19 file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804  python-tk 2.7.15~rc1-1
  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-tk_2.7.15~rc1-1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/libtcl8.6_8.6.8+dfsg-3_amd64.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/libtcl8.6_8.6.8+dfsg-3_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/libtk8.6_8.6.8-4_amd64.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/libtk8.6_8.6.8-4_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/tk8.6-blt2.5_2.5.3+dfsg-4_amd64.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/tk8.6-blt2.5_2.5.3+dfsg-4_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/blt_2.5.3+dfsg-4_amd64.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/blt_2.5.3+dfsg-4_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-lazy-object-proxy_1.3.1-1_amd64.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-lazy-object-proxy_1.3.1-1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-wrapt_1.9.0-3_amd64.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-wrapt_1.9.0-3_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-singledispatch_3.4.0.3-2_all.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-singledispatch_3.4.0.3-2_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-backports.functools-lru-cache_1.4-2_all.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-backports.functools-lru-cache_1.4-2_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-setuptools_39.0.1-2_all.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-setuptools_39.0.1-2_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-astroid_1.6.0-1_all.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-astroid_1.6.0-1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-concurrent.futures_3.2.0-1_all.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-concurrent.futures_3.2.0-1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-isort_4.3.4+ds1-1_all.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-isort_4.3.4+ds1-1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-mccabe_0.6.1-2_all.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-mccabe_0.6.1-2_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-configparser_3.5.0-1_all.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-configparser_3.5.0-1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-logilab-common_1.4.1-1_all.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-logilab-common_1.4.1-1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/pylint_1.8.3-1_all.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/pylint_1.8.3-1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-egenix-mxtools_3.2.9-1_amd64.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-egenix-mxtools_3.2.9-1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-egenix-mxdatetime_3.2.9-1_amd64.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-egenix-mxdatetime_3.2.9-1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-tk_2.7.15~rc1-1_amd64.deb  File not found - /home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/python-tk_2.7.15~rc1-1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I already used answers from [How to change administrator username?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228696/how-to-change-administrator-username) to change my username from "sunbeam" to "admin" but now as I use the "apt-get" to install anything, it tries to fetch files from ***/home/sunbeam/subuntu1804/./repo/..*** which clearly doesn't exist now as sunbeam is renamed to admin. So my question is how to install anything using apt-get as file paths have changed?

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change administrator username?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228696/how-to-change-administrator-username)

Comment: Telling us how you 'changed' your username may be useful, as your paste looks like an incorrect entry in your sources (/etc/apt/sources*)   *or you need to modify those to reflect your new $HOME location as you possibly hard-coded the old directory in your path*

Comment: @Ronald I've edited the question for clarity. My question isn't how to change username, it is now that I've changed username how to configure apt-get to install and fetch files from the new path?

Comment: @guiverc I followed steps in Eric Carvalho's answer https://askubuntu.com/a/228701/922228 to change administrator account's username

Comment: Thanks - I still think it's a hard-coded (and now out-of-date) entry in your sources as previously stated..

Comment: I checked /etc/apt/sources.list and it is still showing the old path. So, What to do now?

Comment: If it contains your old username; edit the file & make it reflect the new directory (*at a minimum*)  I'd use `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` but you can replace `vim` with your favorite editor. or use `sed` etc.   If I've misunderstood your comment, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, but vim isn't allowing to save a read-only file

Comment: `:w! `  == command, write (force)  *explanation as comment has minimum length*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*the following is from comments*

It looks like an incorrect entry in your sources (`/etc/apt/sources`) to me, where you need to modify an entry that points to your old user directory to your new $HOME path (*I'm assuming you hard-coded the old directory as a source which has now changed*)

The command

```
grep sunbeam /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I would expect to produce no results. If it does; these need to be changed to reflect your new $HOME directories name.

The fastest fix in my opinion is to edit the file & make it reflect the new directory.  I would use

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

but you can replace `vim` with your favorite editor, or change the file with `sed` (stream-edit) etc.

Comment: sed command would be like `sudo sed -i 's/sunbeam/admin/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`