# ubuntu 19.04 does not recognize my p/w or my login name/username after tried to change root u/n

Tags: bios

Ubuntu 19.04: problems happen after trying to change the login (root) name: I have managed to enter BIOS GRUB. I would like help to manipulate the BIOS and bring Ubuntu machine back to normal i.e. be able to login in again.At the moment I am unable to login at all. (BIOS used American Megatrends)

I followed instructions about changing the root login name by another. For example modifying a file with password text and remove all entries with the root name, and so on. I thought I was following the instruction very carefully. I entered the AMI Bios and reset the password of administrator and user without effect. Still after I entered the Bios administrator password, still the ubuntu system does not allow me to login. It said "Sorry, that didn't work. Please try again.". The matter I realized that I mess the Ubuntu system of my PC. This BIOS (AMI) does not have a line about "Recovery mode" that will facilitate enter to my file system and do the correction. Equally I would like to ask I should prepare a live Ubuntu SUB and overwrite the old system and bring the Ubuntu system to manufacturing setting. I able to do this approach. What is your advise? Please help!

I followed this link instructions: [How to change administrator username?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228696/how-to-change-administrator-username).

Many thanks for your help I have solved the problem by myself. (1) I built a live sub stick with the brand new Ubuntu 19.04 (2) Changed the PC Bios setting (3) connect the USB onto the PC (4) Made the installation following the instruction given by: https://www.linuxtechi.com/ubuntu-19-04-installation-guide-screenshots/. Great help!

Comment: What exact steps did you take? Did you enable `root` user? Note that `root` user is disabled in Ubuntu for good reasons. Also, you should clarify why BIOS is relevant to the login name. GRUB is not BIOS.

Comment: I get the feeling that you manually modified /etc/passwd (/etc/shadow, or one only) but made an error thus nullifying your account.  If this is so, change it back (using a 'live' system is what I'd use), but we can only guess without clear details of what you did.