# Files/Directories created with no permissions on NFS mount

Tags: mount, permissions, 15.10, nfs

This is reposted here to hopefully attract som answers. Original post: https://superuser.com/questions/1001470/files-directories-created-on-nfs-mount-with-no-permissions

I have a set up with a client running ubuntu 15.10 and a NFS server (Synology NAS, with DSM 5.2). I've succesfully mounted the share I need using the following line in fstab:

```
diskstation:/volume1/share /mnt/DiskStation/share nfs rw 0 0
```

(It doesn't automount - but thats another question :))

My nas is setup with rw privilege and permission to access mounted subfoldes - i use no_root_squash since im not accessing the share as root.

My problem is when I create a file or directory it is created with `d---------` and is obviously inaccessible without running af chmod command first. I would like the files to be created with read and write rights for user and group and read for guests.

I've set my umask to "002" - but it doesn's seem to change a thing.

What can I try/do?

Comment: That mount sttmt seems wrong to me. see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

Comment: What `UID` (`id -u`) are you using on the client? What `UID` does that get mapped to at the server?

Comment: @Rinzwind - i've tried different options, same result. From what I can understand from the NFS man page, and the link you shared, the mount sttmt is with default nfs settings.

Comment: @waltinator - I have a user x on both systems. On the client x has uid 1000 and on the server has uid 1026.

Comment: @waltinator - i kinda get, where this is heading. I'm not familiar at all with the concepts and how they play a role in nfs, but i'm guessing they should match in some way... Can I change the uid somehow? And should it be done on the server or the client?

Comment: So I followed this guide: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16700/how-can-i-change-my-own-user-id/16719#16719 to update my clients users uid. Files are created and are accessible :)

Comment: BTW if you don’t want to use root, you also don’t need to use no-root-squash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing my client's user's uid to match the uid of the user on the server, everything worked perfectly. Follow this guide to change uid of a user: [How can I change my own user ID?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16700/how-can-i-change-my-own-user-id/16719#16719)