# Missing account at start after change userid

Tags: users, groups

The goal was to change userid, groupid to be in the same group with others.

We followed this instruction: [How can I change my own user ID?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16700/how-can-i-change-my-own-user-id)

You can change it in /etc/passwd, /etc/group and /etc/shadow....

first changing passwd to 
user100:x:500:100:..
then changing groups file
user100:x:500:100
, in shadow we did not change anything, because we did not know what to change there. After that we run the two commands below:

```
find / -uid 1007 -exec chown -h 500 {} +  //for userid

find / -gid 1001 -exec chgrp -h 100 {} +  //for group
```

Finally after hours of changing all the files: I log out and I could not log in with my password into my account anymore. After reboot only the guest account showed up.

Is there any chance I can get back my account and my data? I' am in the guest account now and there is no other root account or user account. Please help.

Update (after reversal):

```
grep user99 /mnt/hdd/ect/passwd

user99:x:1007:1001:Leo user99,,,:/home/user99:/bin/bash
```

and for group:

```
grep user99 /mnt/hdd/ect/group

dialout:x:20:user99
sudo:x:27:user99
plugdev:x:46:user99
users:x:1001:user99
user99:x:1001:
bumblebee:x:999:user99,syslog
docker:x:998:user99
```

Comment: Probably there is nothing wrong with your system OR your data - all that's occurred is that the `lightdm` login screen by default does not display accounts whose UID is < 1000

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following in order to return everything back to the previous stage:

- Create boot-able Ubuntu on USB DOK
- Boot your computer with the USB DOK
- Login as `root`
- Mount your hard-disk (as user `root` from the USB DOK Ubuntu)
- Assuming that computer hard-disk located at /dev/sda1

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /mnt/hdd
  sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/hdd
  ```
- Revert the changes you made to the files (can be find under `/mnt/hdd`)
- umount the hard-disk using:

  sudo umount /mnt/hdd
- Power off the computer
- Remove USB DOK
- Power on your computer

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54138/discussion-on-answer-by-yaron-missing-account-at-start-after-change-userid).