# How to change user id for live user?

Tags: boot, live-usb, live-cd

Web search found [How can I change my own user ID?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16700/how-can-i-change-my-own-user-id). However there is no 999 (ubuntu) user in `/etc/passwd` in distro iso file (in `casper/filesystem.squashfs`), `home` folder is empty. AFAIK it means live user is created on-the-fly during boot.

Where and how to change that user id on iso? Not after boot, I want to modify iso file for it to boot with 1000 uid, I know how to rebuild liveUSB iso file.

P.S. checked that on latest 20.04.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

One can use custom init script. Changing grub.cfg and/or isolinux.cfg, line which usually have `quiet splash --` changing to `quiet splash init=/boot/abc.sh --`, where `/boot/abc.sh` is script with contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
groupmod --gid 1000 ubuntu
usermod --uid 1000 ubuntu
exec /sbin/init
```

That script is expected to run after initrd scripts that make live user but before user login.