# I had to reinstall 20.04 and did it badly.. I gave the wrong 'user id' and now cannot access the files... ouch!! how to fix the file / dir mess?

Tags: chown

I have used Ubuntu Linux for at least 10 years, and had a problem. So I re-installed 20.04 and forgot my 'user id' and gave it a new one. Installation went well, but all those disks not involved have the old user id.. I tried CHOWN a few times... complete failure.

What can I do, other than reinstall with the correct user id?

Answer (score 2):

`chown` cannot be a complete failure. It is the method to change ownerschip to the new uid. To change ownership in a directory Documents recursively on all files and subdirectories, one can do `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/Documents`. Root (`sudo`) must do that because a normal user is not allowed to change ownerships of files of other users. `$USER` will be substituted by the login of the current user, and `~` expands to the home directory of the current user.

Alternatively, you can [change the uid](https://askubuntu.com/a/16822/558158) of your current user to match the uid to the old uid.

The first user created on a new Ubuntu system always has uid 1000.

Comment: `$ ls -n` will show the NUMERIC user and group ID's - for changing it on he newly created user.