# Git pull and vpn asking for old root password

Tags: 20.04, permissions, sudo, vpn, git

I changed the system password recently. Whenever I am trying to do a git pull or a vpn connection, I am asked for the "previous" Ubuntu password. May I know why this is happening?

Comment: Which password did you change? `git pull` shouldn't ask a password.

Comment: To be honest, I do not recall exactly what I did. My root and login are new. But the git pull and vpn are asking for old password.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "My root and login are new". If you can't recall what you did, it is impossible to suggest anything.

Comment: By root, I meant the `sudo` password. By login, I meant the password I use to login to Ubuntu. This is a personal laptop and there is only one account.

Comment: "sudo password" should be the same as your user password. Did you create a new user? Did you make the new user an administrator?

Comment: Yes. I had to change user ID for which I needed to create temporary account with admin rights: https://askubuntu.com/a/16822/333115

Comment: I went through your answer. I deleted the temporary account immediately after changing user ID a while ago. Now there is only one user, which is the administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you created a new user and the new user is not an administrator.

Go to Settings -> Users and give your user this privilege.

Maybe your Home directory is still owned by another user.

Run

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/
```

Be careful, don't skip `~`.